# How do static variables work in Junit when initiailizing them from multiple modules?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Lets assume I have a class with a static variable like so:

```
public class var{
    public static String myvar = "thor";
}
```

And junit classes like so:

```
public class test1{
    @Test
    public void test(){
       var.myvar = "1";
    }
}

public class test2{
     @Test
    public void test(){
       var.myvar = "1";
    }
}
```

When running both junit classes, will they share the same variable? or somehow junit makes these variables thread safe so each module has its own static variable?

update: if they case is the former how can you set up a static variable for the entire junit build?

Comment: "how can you set up a static variable for the entire junit build?" `@BeforeClass`?

Comment: Mutable global state - such as this - tends to indicate a design issue. Why do you need this to be changed in this way for tests? What stops this being changed for *non*-tests?

Comment: There are son many modules that depend on the initialization of a static variable. If the variable is not initialized, it will throw a null pointer exception. That's the problem right now. Is there a way to initiliaze static variables for the entire lifecycle of the junit clases?

Comment: Then in that case, you need to create common constants, which will be used for entire application.

Comment: @Fernando I'm not saying there's a problem with initializing it, I'm saying there's a problem with allowing (and needing) its value to be changed after it has been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

A static variable is linked with the class , so since there is only one .class instance , the variable myvar will also be one and wherever you access it, it will the same varaible.